# How to add number of days in date which is in String format in Android

Tags: android

I have one Edit Text and one textview. Textview will display a date in String format.If user enters 10 in edittext then automatically date in textview should update to display date which is 10 days ahead.

How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Rohan

Comment: Which part of the task you do not understand how to accomplish?

Answer (score 8):

pls see this and implement

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText edt_day;
String day = "";
int next_date = 0;
TextView txt_next_date;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edt_day = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_day);
    txt_next_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_next_date);

    edt_day.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // Log.i("KeyBoard" ,"Inside the Edit Text");
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {

                next_date = Integer.parseInt(edt_day.getText().toString());

                Calendar someDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                someDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, +next_date);
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(someDate.getTime());
                Log.e("minite", "formattedDate=" + formattedDate);
                txt_next_date.setText(formattedDate);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
   }
}




<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_day"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:hint="Enter no of Day"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_next_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: pls  accept my ans.......

Answer (score 0):

First of all You have to use TextWatcher for as you say that user enter value in edittext and value should be change in Textview. and other functions you have not described properly,but you can do it using Textwatcher.

Comment: Lets say user enter 10 in edittext then 10 days must be added in textview date with all validations and textview value should change to +10 days. Month days n year validations should be there..